# Javascript code loads under 2s in Chrome, 4s in Firefox, but takes 20s in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Very slow speed of loading in Internet Explorer, and slightly slow in Microsoft Edge.

Basically, the page freezes for 20 seconds, while executing js code. The code brings in a 5mb xml file and displays the contents as tr's in a table. Which brings thousands of job postings.

It all works fine in Chrome, practically instant, however Microsoft browsers are acting pretty slow.

Any thoughts?

The code is long, so here it is in js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/t3h4zqt5/

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}   

    $.fn.extend({ 
       xml_parser : function(el) {

        //Construct and display preloader
         $('<div id="preload_xml" />').html('<img src="/wp-content/themes/Divi-Child/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading data" /><h3>Setting up the Job List...</h3>').prependTo($('body'));

            el.hide();
            var e = el;

            //Get XML Data
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'externalxmlfile',
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function(data) {

                  //Remove preloader HTML & show data
                  $('#preload_xml').remove();
                  el.show();
                var entries     = $(data).find('job'),
                    xmlArr      = [],
                    xmlArrCity   = [];

                    var xml_zip_array = 
                    entries.each(function() {

                        //Atrributes from XML nodes
                        var xml_headline = $(this).find('headline').text(),
                            xml_city = $(this).find('city').text(),
                            xml_application = $(this).find('application').text(),
                            xml_bodycopy = $(this).find('bodycopy').text(),
                            xml_zip = $(this).find('zip').text(),
                            xml_benefits = $(this).find('benefits').text(),
                            xml_qualifications = $(this).find('qualifications').text(),
                            xml_state = $(this).find('state').text(),
                            xml_subhead = $(this).find('subhead').text();
                        var xml_drivertype = $(this).find('drivertypeID').text();
                        switch(xml_drivertype){
                                case "19":
                                    xml_drivertype = "Lease Purchase";
                                    break;
                                case "20":
                                    xml_drivertype = "Company Driver Team";
                                    break;
                                case "21":
                                    xml_drivertype = "Student";
                                    break;
                                case "63":
                                    xml_drivertype = "Dedicated Driver";
                                    break;
                                case "64":
                                    xml_drivertype = "OTR";
                                    break;
                                case "65":
                                    xml_drivertype = "Regional Drivers";
                                    break;
                                case "66":
                                    xml_drivertype = "Owner Operator";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    xml_drivertype = "Undefined ID";
                        };
                      xmlArrCity.push(xml_city);
                      // Add matched items to an array
                      xmlArr += '<tr data-filtercriteria="'+ xml_drivertype +'">';

                        xmlArr += '<td class="clickableTd">'+ xml_headline +'</td>';
                        xmlArr += '<td class="clickableTd">'+ xml_drivertype +'</td>';
                        xmlArr += '<td class="clickableTd">'+ xml_city +'</td>';
                        xmlArr += '<td class="clickableTd stateTd">'+ xml_state +'</td>';
                        xmlArr += '<td class="popupButton">+</td><td class="popup"><div class="popupContainer"><div class="popupExit">X</div><div class="headline">'+ xml_headline +'</div><div class="popupBodyContainer"><div class="subhead">'+ xml_subhead +'</div><div class="bodycopy">'+ xml_bodycopy +'</div><div class="benefits">Benefits:</br>'+ xml_benefits +'</div><div class="qualifications">Qualifications:</br>'+ xml_qualifications +'</div><div class="application"><a href="'+ xml_application +'" target="_blank">Apply now</a></div></div></div></td>';
                   xmlArr += '<td class="zipTd">'+ xml_zip +'</td>';
                      xmlArr += '</tr>';

                    }); // end each loop

                      $(xmlArr).appendTo(el.find('table > tbody'));


                      //Add sort and zebra stripe to table
                       window.setTimeout(function(){ el.find('table').tablesorter({sortList:[[0,0],[0,0]], widgets: ['zebra']});}, 120);
                      el.find('table').hide().slideDown('200');

                      //Filter results functionality
                     var nav_link = $('#xml_nav li a');

                     nav_link.click( function() {

                        var tr         = el.find('tbody > tr'),
                            attr_class = $(this).attr('class');
                        tr.show(); //Show all rows


                            tr.removeClass('stripe');   
                            $('table > tbody > tr:visible:odd').addClass('stripe');
                      });

            var zipFinal;
            var zipFinal2;

var columnFilters = [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]; // add as many as you have columns
var zipColumnNo = 6;
var stateColumnNo = 3;
var cityColumnNo = 2;
var driverColumnNo = 1;
var cityLength = 0;
                            // toggle first-column filter:
var fresh = 0;
                function applyFilter(filter) {

                    $('tr').each(function() {
                        $(this).toggle( // show when no TD has mismatching content
                        !$(this).find('td').filter(function(idx) {
                        // return true when content does not match the filter on this column
                        return filter[idx] && Object.keys(filter[idx]).length &&
                                !filter[idx].hasOwnProperty($(this).text()) && !filter[cityColumnNo].hasOwnProperty($(this).text().toString().substring(0, cityLength).toLowerCase());                                  
                        }).length
                        );
                    });
};

        $('body').on('click', '#zipButton', function() {

        if($('#zipid2').val() == "") {
            $('tr').show();
            columnFilters[zipColumnNo] = {};
            applyFilter(columnFilters);

        if ($("tbody tr:visible").length === 0) {
      $(".resetFilter").addClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
      else {
      $(".resetFilter").removeClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
        }
        else {
                        var apiUrlZip = $('#zipid2').val();
                        var apiUrlMiles = $('#zipMiles').val();
                        var apiUrl = "http://api.truckingfeeds.com/ziplist.aspx?key=ced2929f-3621-496f-89aa-1f64fc721b06&zip="+apiUrlZip+"&miles="+apiUrlMiles;
                        $.ajax({
                            async: false,
                            url: apiUrl,
                            success: function(response){
                                zipFinal = response;
                                zipFinal2 = zipFinal.split(',').map(Number);

                        }});

    var newFilter = {};
        // turn zipFinal2[] into object with values as properties for faster lookup
        zipFinal2.forEach(function(zip) {
            newFilter[zip] = 1;
        });
    columnFilters[zipColumnNo] = newFilter;
    applyFilter(columnFilters);
    $("#xml_wrapper .tableContainer").css("display", "block");
        if ($("tbody tr:visible").length === 0) {
      $(".resetFilter").addClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
      else {
      $(".resetFilter").removeClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
      $('#statesUS').val("ALL").change();
      $('#jobCity').val("").change();
            }});


    $("#jobCity").on('keyup change', function() {
            if($(this).val() == "") {
            $('tr').show();
            columnFilters[cityColumnNo] = {};
            applyFilter(columnFilters);

        if ($("tbody tr:visible").length === 0) {
      $(".resetFilter").addClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
      else {
      $(".resetFilter").removeClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
        }
        else {
    columnFilters[cityColumnNo] = {}; // no filter
         cityLength = $(this).val().length;
         columnFilters[cityColumnNo][$(this).val().toLowerCase()] = 1;
    applyFilter(columnFilters);
    $("#xml_wrapper .tableContainer").css("display", "block");
        if ($("tbody tr:visible").length === 0) {
      $(".resetFilter").addClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
      else {
      $(".resetFilter").removeClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
      }
});
$('#driverTypes').change(function () {
    columnFilters[driverColumnNo] =  {}; // no filter
    if (this.selectedIndex) {
         // filter second column on text in selected option
         columnFilters[driverColumnNo][$(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).text()] = 1;
    }
    applyFilter(columnFilters);
    $("#xml_wrapper .tableContainer").css("display", "block");
        if ($("tbody tr:visible").length === 0) {
      $(".resetFilter").addClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
      else {
      $(".resetFilter").removeClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
});
$('#statesUS').change(function () {
    columnFilters[stateColumnNo] =  {}; // no filter
    if (this.selectedIndex) {
         // filter second column on text in selected option
         columnFilters[stateColumnNo][$(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).text()] = 1;
    }
    applyFilter(columnFilters);
    $("#xml_wrapper .tableContainer").css("display", "block");
        if ($("tbody tr:visible").length === 0) {
      $(".resetFilter").addClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
      else {
      $(".resetFilter").removeClass('resetFilterVisible')
      }
});

$('body').on('click', '.resetFilterButton', function() {
$('#zipid2').val("").change();
$('#zipMiles').val($("#zipMiles option:first").val()).change();
$("#xml_wrapper .tableContainer").css("display", "none");
$('#jobCity').val("").change();
$('#driverTypes').val($("#driverTypes option:first").val()).change();
$('#statesUS').val($("#statesUS option:first").val()).change();
$('tr').show();
columnFilters[zipColumnNo] = {};
    applyFilter(columnFilters);
$(".resetFilter").removeClass('resetFilterVisible');
      });
```

For your info, here is the page http://usxjobs.johngroupinteractive.com/job-search

Thanks

Comment: As a side note, are you making each client download and process this file? I would look to change that pattern to something much more scalable if so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is poorly formatted/indented (both in sample above, as well as in JSFiddle) so it's a bit hard to follow... but generally speaking I'm surprised it's as fast in Chrome and Firefox as it allegedly is.

In a nutshell, your code is [thrashing the DOM](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing?hl=en).

First, your code loops through a 5MB file to build a DOM structure -- at least you do this in a single pass here:

```
$(xmlArr).appendTo(el.find('table > tbody'));
```

But then you do a series of style adjustments and other things to this DOM. Each of these operations is asking the browser to apply CSS (and/or other things) to the gigantic amount of DOM you just rendered. Chrome and Firefox (Edge too... really any "modern" browser) handle these things relatively well, but older versions of IE do not.

To speed things up, my advice is to apply any CSS classes, filters, and other adjustments *before* you render that gigantic table to the DOM. That way you can avoid asking the browser to loop over (presumably) thousands of DOM elements multiple times.

---

There's also likely other things contributing to performance problems here. I'm just pointing out the more obvious issue.

Comment: Thank you, I have reworked the rendering part in php, now everything is put on the page before the page loads, and by hiding the elements in css, I avoid long loading times. The elements are shown only when someone selects a filter. Instant loading in all browsers, except for IE, still takes IE a couple seconds to understand all that information. The amount of html alone on the page is over 6mb. Thanks